# How to map two-dimensional array into HashMap using first dimension as keys with stream

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, java-stream

I need map two dimensional array

```
String [][] values = {{key1, key2,...}, {value1, value2,...}}
```

into `HashMap<String, String>`.

I tried to use stream `Arrays.stream(values).collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key[0], value -> value[1])`

I got `key1=key2, value1=value2`. 
I need `key1=value1, key2=value2`

Is there some solution using stream for this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using this:

```
 HashMap<String,String> map = 
        new HashMap<String, String>(IntStream
                                    .range(0,values[0].length)
                                    .boxed()
                                    .collect(Collectors.
                                             toMap(i -> values[0][i], i -> values[1][i])));
```

Comment: Make it cleaner : `Map<String, String> oneDMap = IntStream.range(0, values[0].length).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> values[0][i], i -> values[1][i]))`

Comment: If it really needs to be a `HashMap` rather than an unspecified `Map`, you can specify `HashMap::new` as map supplier directly to the `toMap` collector, instead of copying the entire result map.